# Matching One Table's Entry With a Data Point Between Two Dates in Another Table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables. They are currently in Access 2010 but will eventually be migrated to a Microsoft SQL 2010 DBMS. One is called EmployeeWages and the other is TimeClock. EmployeeWages consists of the employee ID, a wage, and an effective date. The TimeClock table has the employee ID, a wage associated with the employee, and a date that the wage is effective.

What I need to do is match up the correct wage to entry that the employee worked. Currently the table has a TimeIn and a TimeOut field. For simplicity's sake in this question I will have already calculated the hours worked, however if I can get everything in one query that would be great.

```
EmployeeWage
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  EmployeeID  |  RecordNum  |  EffectiveDate  |  WorkType  |  Wage  |
-+------------+-+-----------+-+---------------+-+----------+-+------+-
|  6240        |      1      |     1/18/13     |    Line    |   6    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  6240        |      2      |     4/1/13      |    Bench   |   7    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  6240        |      3      |     6/1/13      |    Min     |   7.35 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  6240        |      4      |     6/23/13     |    Bench   |   5    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  6240        |      5      |     6/24/13     |    Bench   |   6.25 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  6240        |      5      |     6/25/13     |    Bench   |   7.25 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then

```
TimeClock
--------------------------------------------------
|  EmployeeID  |  WorkType  |  Work Date|  Hours |
-+------------+-+----------+-+---------+-+------+-
|  6240        |    Line    |  6/22/13  |   5    |
--------------------------------------------------
|  6240        |    Bench   |  6/22/13  |   7    |
--------------------------------------------------
|  6240        |    Bench   |  6/23/13  |   5    |
--------------------------------------------------
|  6240        |    Bench   |  6/24/13  |   6.25 |
--------------------------------------------------
|  6240        |    Min     |  6/24/13  |   2    |
--------------------------------------------------
```

The resulting matched up table should look like...

```
TimeClock
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  EmployeeID  |  WorkType  |  Work Date|  Hours |  Wage  |
-+------------+-+----------+-+---------+-+------+-+------+-
|  6240        |    Line    |  6/22/13  |   5    |   6    |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  6240        |    Bench   |  6/22/13  |   6.25 |   7    |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  6240        |    Bench   |  6/23/13  |   6    |   5    |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  6240        |    Bench   |  6/24/13  |   5.5  |   6.25 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  6240        |    Min     |  6/24/13  |   2    |   7.35 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help to get me there would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll need an extra condition in the join, otherwise a (partial) Carthesian product will result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.EmployeeID, T.WorkType, T.[Work Date], T.Hours, 
(SELECT Max(E.EffectiveDate) 
FROM EmployeeWage E
WHERE T.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
AND T.WorkType = E.WorkType
AND E.EffectiveDate <= T.[Work Date]) AS ActiveDate, 
E.Wage as Wage
FROM TimeClock T, EmployeeWage EW
WHERE T.EmployeeID = EW.EmployeeID
AND TW.WorkType = EW.WorkType 
AND E.EffectiveDate = ActiveDate
```

Note that I don't have MS-Access and haven't tried this out. Let me know if it helps or errors, if any.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a perfect way to get your results with a single query, but this will give you the basic information that you need:

```
SELECT TimeClock.EmployeeID, TimeClock.WorkType, TimeClock.WorkDate, EmployeeWage.EffectiveDate, TimeClock.Hours, EmployeeWage.Wage
  FROM EmployeeWage INNER JOIN TimeClock 
  ON EmployeeWage.EmployeeID = TimeClock.EmployeeID
    AND TimeClock.WorkType = EmployeeWage.WorkType
  WHERE TimeClock.WorkDate >= EmployeeWage.EffectiveDate;
```

Comment: @shahkalpesh I keep getting prompted to "Enter Parameter Value" for E.Wage, TW.WorkType, E.EffectiveDate, ActiveDate. I changed E.Wage to EW.Wage, TW.WorkType to T.WorkType, E.EffectiveDate to EW.EffectiveDate. Now all I get is the prompt for ActiveDate...

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I put up my code before testing it and have made edits since testing. Please try the new code and see if that works for you. Note that _WorkDate_ might be different in your DB.